# HTML - Flexbox align-self not applying

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm learning html/css and it seems `align-self` for class `item-2` isn't applying but in the instructors video its working. I just wanted to know what went wrong in the code?

Here is the complete code and also shared on https://jsfiddle.net/nk0sp2ev/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flex Align</title>
  <style>
    #container {
      background: #555;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      height: 600px;
      align-items: baseline;
      align-content: space-between;
    }

    .item-2 {
      align-self: flex-end;
    }

    .item {
      background: #f4f4f4;  
      border: #ccc solid 1px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1rem;
      margin: 0.5rem;
      flex-basis: 200px;
    }


  </style>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="item item-1"><h3>Item 1</h3></div>
    <div class="item item-2"><h3>Item 2</h3></div>
    <div class="item item-3"><h3>Item 3</h3></div>  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `flex-wrap: wrap;` from your container, it works. Maybe the instructor had already removed it ;-)

The best guide to flexbox I know is this one: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
It explains that the wrap propperty will will wrap items onto multiple lines, from top to bottom.